# How to include dependency files in maven assembly

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a maven project which is configured (via the use of pom.xml and assembly.xml) to package a zip file containing both the compiled webapp (war file) and all files under src/main/folder alongside it whenever we run `mvn clean package assembly:single`.

This project imports/uses another maven project (which becomes a jar file) and that project in turn also imports/uses a third maven project (again a jar file).

The third project also contains some files inside src/main/folder as well which I'd like to be placed alongside the other files in the zip file whenever I build the main project (the one on top of the chain that becomes a war file).

Is it possible somehow to tell maven to include all files in a specific folder inside all it's dependencies (Or in one specific dependency) alongside in the zip file?

Answer (score 2):

Start here: [Maven: The Complete Reference - 8.5. Controlling the Contents of an Assembly](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/assemblies-sect-controlling-contents.html)

Note that if you `deploy` a Maven project with `assembly:assembly` (which you really should configure as a `<build>` plugin, not use on the command line), the assemblies get "attached" to the project and installed in the repository. You can then reach them using the Maven dependency notation, i.e. `mygroup:myartifact:extrafiles:zip`

I've found the Assembly descriptor `<dependencySets>` cumbersome to configure. They really are for the simple case (including the JAR files your application needs at runtime).

Here is the general approach I would take for your desired outcome:

1. Use [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html) `dependency:copy` to download the specific files from the other projects, placing them under a sub-directory of `target/`
2. Configure your assembly descriptor to add those downloaded/extracted files to your final assembly artifact.

Alternatively, hack something together using [Maven Ant Run Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the dependency:copy plugin and it seems to work however it copies the whole jar rather than the specific file contained in that project. I haven't found a way to specify the file(s) only and exclude the jar itself.

Comment: Learn about Maven artifact coordinates, which I mentioned.

Comment: See this helpful page: http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/12/maven-dependency-resolution-a-repository-perspective/

Answer (score 1):

You will need to produce an additional assembly from the third project to package up the extra files. Append the assembly id so it produces a package named something like third-1.0.0-extrafiles.zip

Then add this as a dependency of your first project using <type>extrafiles</type> in the dependency descriptor. In the assembly for the first project you'll have to tell it to "unpack" the dependencies of this type (so you don't get a zip in a zip)

Comment: Thank you. Could you give a bit mroe details on how to do the unpacking and what do you mean by appending the assembly id?

Comment: Where you specify the assembly in your pom there is the option to append the assembly id. if you have an assembly with if "foo" that produces a zip file then this option changes the name of the package produced. project.1.0.0.zip becomes project-1.0.0-foo.zip
Then in another project you depend on this package separately from the regular jar by using the &lt;type&gt; parameter.  This is the same mechanism used for src-jars etc.

Comment: In your first project assembly you probably want all the dependent jars included as is without unzipping the jars. So the jar dependencies go in the assembly "packed". But in your case you want the files from the third project in the zip as regular files "unpacked"

Comment: Aha. It looks like, according to this http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html , that it's set to true by default (and I indeed get the id name on the zip file when running assembly:single in the main project). I am uncertain what you mean by the <type>extrafiles</type> in the dependency. In the pom of the second project I have the third project as a dependency and in the pom of the first project I have the second project as a dependency but none of them have the type tag as that is already specified in the pom of the second and third project already (as jar)

Comment: Do you mean I should add the third project as a dependency of the first (besides being a dependency of the second) and use the id of the assembly as the type? Not sure how exactly that works but I'll give it a try. Also I was hoping not to have the third project be a dependency of the first since it is already a dependency of the second but I guess there is no way to tell maven to simply propagate the files upwards.